# Ansible development modules - where to download

Tags: ansible

How do I install/download the Ansible development modules?

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/modules/list_of_windows_modules.html

```
# rpm -qa |grep ansib
ansible-2.6.20-1.el7ae.noarch

# cat win-list-services.yml
---
- name: Get info for all installed services
  hosts: '{{ host }}'
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    execute: false
  tasks:
  - name: Get info for all installed services
    win_service_info:
    register: servicelist


# ansible-playbook -v win-list-services.yml 
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to be in '/root/playbook/win-list-services.yml': line 8, column 5, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  tasks:
  - name: Get info for all installed services
    ^ here
```

Comment: You have to [run from source](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#running-ansible-from-source-devel) or wait until the next version containing the `win_service_info` module is published but you will have to add an [alternate rpm source](https://releases.ansible.com/ansible/rpm) to get the latest versions or change installation method (and I [strongly suggest pip for that](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#installing-ansible-with-pip))

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the windows modules are part of the move to ansible-collections, and thus you *may* be able to run them using a "normal" ansible 2.9 install after [following the collection install instructions](https://github.com/ansible-collections/ansible.windows#installation-and-usage)

The pragmatic implication is that it is unlikely you can follow Zeitounator's instructions since those windows modules no longer live in the ansible repo, so using `pip install -e` will not provide them (unless you use a git sha earlier than the current `devel`)

However, either way, being on ansible 2.6 as shown in your question is quite old, so you will want to get on a modern version anyway

Answer (score 0):

So far, I found out that we can download from Ansible Galaxy.

*win_service_info* is available from below.

https://galaxy.ansible.com/ansible/windows

It require Ansible 2.9 as described by mdaniel.